# Convert polygon to polyline with adjacent polygon IDs

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, convert

Is it possible to convert a polygon to polyline in QGIS WITH the adjacent polygon IDs for each polyline segment? I know one can do this in ArcToolbox but need to find out how to do it in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

It was not clear to me if the question was about a single QGIS tool to do the tasks to [A] convert a polygon to polylines, and [B] return a measure to describe which polygon is adjacent to one another, all at once.

This is an ad-hoc response assuming the mentioned ArcTool is [`Polygon Neighbors`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/polygon-neighbors.htm) tool, hence about the task [B] only.

---

Polygon neighbors tool can work for cases of `Edge adjacent` and `Node adjacent` - polygons can be attached to each other at edges or at nodes:

(1) Edge adjacent relationships - YES, there is **Shared polygon edges** tool

Red polylines on the attached image (below) is an output of QGIS Processing Toolbox - `SAGA | Vector polygon tools | Shared polygon edges`.

[image]

The associated attribute table is like below, which shows adjacent polygon IDs:

[image]

(2) Node adjacent polygons - Probably NOT

As shown in the above image, Polygon 1 and Polygon 6 share the part of their edges but not completely. ArcToolbox tool may report back this case as a `Node adjacent` (please correct me if I am wrong). This is rejected by `QGIS - SAGA / Shared Polygon Edges` tool.

---

If this meets your selection criteria (I mean, if it is how do you want them to be **adjacent**), this tool can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot and provides me something to work with.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot and provides me something to work with. As regards the question about polygons 1 and 6, ArcToolox identifies a common boundary where the two polygons abut and would not identify anything for the situation where there is an unfilled gap between the polygons. Thanks for the help.